# How do I add JS Snippet to CMS Page?

Tags: magento-1.9

How can I add a JavaScript snippet to the head of a CMS page?

I don't want to reference a JS file.

Instead I would like to add the piece of JS directly (it is to preload an image so only 2 lines).

Answer (score 1):

you can simply add in the content area of your cms page the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //your js here
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simple add you in `design` tab `Layout Update XML` field

```
<reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs">
                <script>yourfolder/script.js</script>
            </action>

</reference>
```

you script will be added in `head`.